# How can I use \n in \directlua{} to replace empty lines

Tags: lua, directlua

Let’s assume I have a file `file.txt` containing

```
This is

a test
```

and I want to replace the contents (from within TeX) with

```
This is\par a test
```

I tried to use Lua but stuck with the `\n` in the replacement text.

Here’s the (not working) code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{file.txt}
This is

a test
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Test

\directlua{
   local file = io.open("file.txt")
   local fileedited = io.open("editedfile.txt", "w")
   local content = file:read "*a"
   file:close()
   contentedited = string.gsub(content, "\n\n", "\\par")
   fileedited:write(contentedited)
   fileedited:close()
}
\end{document}
```

I’m not bound to use Lua for this but I can't use any command line tools (shell escape) since the file must run on different computers, where I can’t make sure that the command line tool is available. In the end, the filename should be an argument (`#1`) given from the TeX code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{file.txt}
This is

a test
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Test

\directlua{
   local file = io.open("file.txt")
   local fileedited = io.open("editedfile.txt", "w")
   local content = file:read "*a"
   file:close()
   contentedited = string.gsub(content, "\string\n\string\n", "\string\\par ")
   fileedited:write(contentedited)
   fileedited:close()
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

the contents of `\directlua` are expanded, like `\write` before Lua sees them, so your `\\` is latex newline macros, and `\n` iis an undefined command, you can use

```
\directlua{\detokenize{
   local file = io.open("file.txt")
   local fileedited = io.open("editedfile.txt", "w")
   local content = file:read "*a"
   file:close()
   contentedited = string.gsub(content, "\n\n", "\\par")
   fileedited:write(contentedited)
   fileedited:close()
}}
```

to prevent expansion.

Comment: Thanks but this would also prevent the use of `#1`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Tobi you don't have to put `\detokenize` around the whole thing, `\detokenize{\n\n", "\\par"}` would work, as would `\string\n\string\n", "\string\\par"` and no `\detokenize` at all,

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I though about that but was to lazy to try it ;-)